# Change ordering of initials in biblatex style

Tags: biblatex

I'm not very experienced with `biblatex`, but I hope that the answer to this question will be relatively simple. I'm using the `authoryear` style, and my references in the reference list appear like the following:

> Wilson, R. T. and E. J. Milton (2010). Automated Selection of Suitable
>   Atmospheric Correction Sites. In: Remote Sensing and Photogrammetry
>   Society Annual Conference, September 2010, Cork, Ireland.

This looks great, apart from the fact that the first author and the second author have their initials in a different order. For the first author it is `Surname, Initials` and the second author is `Initials, Surname`.

So, my question is threefold: Is there a simple option to change this? If not, can I simply modify the `.bbx` file to change this? If not, is there another `biblatex` style already available that does this without changing the rest of the reference style too much?

Comment: Is the _only_ change you need to the names or is this part of a wider need for a slightly different style?

Comment: Only to the names I think. The rest of the style looks perfect for what I want - it's just the ordering of the names and initials that are the problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A simple approach is to set

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}
```

or

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```

after loading `biblatex`, with the one to choose being dependent on where you want initials to appear.

Comment: I hate having to remember this command for every new document or search this answer. I vote to make `last-first` a default package option `:)`

Answer (score 3):

As Joseph has pointed out,

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{<formatting macro>}
```

may be used to change the name format of the `authoryear` style and its variants. This also works for the `authortitle` and `verbose` style families. To change the name format of the `numeric` and `alphabetic` style families, you have to use

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{<formatting macro>}
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally use the natbib styles, you can find them on CTAN. After placing the style files in the right directory you can use the styles in e.g. the following way:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=nature, citestyle=numeric-comp, sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}%this style compresses the numbering
```

And It does as you want. Just tested it quickly with my own library using a dual author reference, and this is how it is displayed.

1. De Vries, R. & Visser, J. Regulation of the feruloyl esterase (faeA) gene from
   Aspergillus niger. Applied and Environmental Microbiology 65, 5500 (1999).

Comment: These are not `natbib` styles: they are custom ones for `biblatex` (I write the `nature` style!).

Comment: @Timtico, how could get we get
 [1] De Vries, R. & Visser, J.  (1999). Regulation of the feruloyl esterase (faeA) gene from Aspergillus niger. Applied and Environmental Microbiology 65, 5500.